# Disable opening quick find on FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

At my site I'm using keys for play sounds via JS. This works fine in Chrome and other similar engines. But Firefox opens quick search bar on any alphabet keypress. 
I know this feature might be disabled in Firefox settings.

But maybe there any possibility to disable this behavior via JS?